# How to 'add' FQ12 points (result of pairings) when using Ethereum's py_ecc library

Tags: python, zksnark, pairings

When implementing an algorithm like groth16, the verification step involves the `addition` of higher-order field elements (FQ12) resulting from pairings. How can this be achieved through Ethereum's [py_ecc](https://github.com/ethereum/py_pairing/blob/master/py_ecc/bn128/bn128_pairing.py) library, since simple arithmetic addition is invalid?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like the following:

```
from py_ecc.fields import optimized_bn128_FQ12 as FQ12
first = pairing(B_2, neg(A_1))
second = pairing(beta_G2, alpha_G1)
third = pairing(G2, C_1)
print("first pairing == second pairing:", final_exponentiate(first * second * third) == FQ12.one())
```

Source: https://github.com/zigtur/Groth16/blob/main/Groth16.ipynb

Comment: Thank you! This works.

Heads up for future readers of this answer: The pairing and FQ12 must belong to the same curve (the standard bn128 or the optimised one) to prevent type conflicts in Python.